# html5 required attribute custom validation message not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a simple form with two inputs and a submit button. I need to display the message depending on the lang attribute. When I click on submit button it displays the message even though the field is filled with valid data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="get">
<input type="text" value="" oninvalid="check(event)"   required/>
<input type="text" value="" oninvalid="check(event)" required/>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function check(e) {

var a=document.documentElement.lang;
var validateMsg=(a=="ar"?"In arabic":"Plz enter on Alphabets");

 var input = e.target;

 if(input.validity.valid){
    return true;
 }else{
     
     input.setCustomValidity(validateMsg);  
     return false;
 }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

- `check(event)` is meaningless. The event parameter is passed internally
- checking validity inside the `oninvalid` handler is useless

If you use only `oninvalid`, you won't be able to change back the validation message once the user starts filling the field. You should use the `change`, `keyup` or `keydown` event for that, depending on the reactivity you want.

This could work:

```
<input type="text" value="" onchange="check" required />

// ...

function check(e) {
    var input = e.target;
    var msg = "";
    if(!input.validity.valid) {
        var a=document.documentElement.lang;
        msg=(a=="ar"?"In arabic":"Plz enter on Alphabets");
    }
    input.setCustomValidity(msg);  
}
```